# How to add a different specific image for each page in a region?

Tags: blocks, media, theming

I want to have a **different specific** image on every page in the same region for each. I don't want to have to create separate blocks for each one. Is there an easier way? I will be getting the images from the directory.

Thanks

Comment: what you mean 'different image'? is that a content type image field? or you want lo load from an image directory? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have a content type which contains the field image and that image field have to displayed randomly in different pages. If so the solution would be

- Create a **block** view and add the content type as criteria and the `field:image`
- *Remove all sort criteria* and just add `Global: Random` as a sort criteria
- specify only one content should be displayed in Pager option

That's it. Now you can render it and it will randomly display the image in each page

Comment: Hey good answer. but I think it's doesn't work for images. I've set up the same settings for my view and tested it. but the same image showing on every page. Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes I created one and its still working fine.. remove all sort criteria and just add global:random in sort criteria

Comment: Yes, Great. it's working. +1 to your answer.please mention in the answer that 'remove all sort criteria except `global:random` in sort criteria. :)

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the  [Random Image Block](https://github.com/stephengaito/drupal-randomImageBlock) module.

> This Drupal 7.x Random Image Block module displays random images taken from a specified directory. It obtains its list of images to display by requiring a php file (imageList.php) which defines one function which returns a keyed-array of keyed-arrays. This random image block is not cached so a new image is displayed for each hit to the website.